# Calling android dialog without it fading the background

Tags: android, dialog, view

I have this nice dialog view I set my UserInputDialog class to:

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="What is your name Captain?"
        >
        </TextView>
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        >
        </EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel">
        </Button>               
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want my dialog to show up but for the background to not fade out.  Is this possible?  Cause the view that calls this dialog has a neato background I would like to be shown as a backdrop to the dialog.

I found this online:

```
<style name="doNotDim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0</item>
</style >
```

but not sure how to apply that to my dialog?  I have a class called `public class UserInputDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener`.  It sets its content view to the layout described above.

I think I am doing this all right, just not sure how to add that style so I can NOT fade the background.

Secondary question:  Can you get new looks on your dialog (by say having an image or icon display with your text there) by using Themes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Create a res/values/styles.xml file and add this to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And apply the theme to your activity.

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDim">
```

Comment: will that make every dialog that I call from that activity use the same style?

Comment: Actually that is a style setting on the Activity, meaning the Activity will not dim ever. Has nothing to do with the dialog.

Comment: Work perfectly and supported  since  api 3

Answer (score 179):

You can also remove the dim effect by code with the following:

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: Great! And `dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.1f)` would have slight dim. Value should be within [0.0f, 1.0f].

Comment: Remember to do this after the dialog is available. I tried in onAttach and it did not work. In onViewCreated it worked :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom style and place it in your values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="YourCustomStyle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

To set a style to an individual dialog you can use

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.YourCustomStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

For displaying dialog like **TrueCaller** do this:

In `styles.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="myBackgroundStyle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml` do this:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/myBackgroundStyle">
```