# How to set dialog's position?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have made a custom dialog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myBackgroundStyle"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
</resources>
```

[image: screenshot]

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

dialog.show();

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.y = 225; params.x = 225;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;       
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But the problem is that it appears in the top left corner and I can't find a way to place it where I need it. `params.y=225; params.x=225;` somehow don't affect it.

Any ideas?

---

edit:
If I have the xml like that ( style/Theme.Dialog ), then the parameters and location work fine, but a modal shadow appears. Is there a way to remove it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="myBackgroundStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`Theme.Panel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Panel) as the style's `parent` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Try creating a new set of parameters:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.y = 225; params.x = 225;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;       
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

**Edit:** if you want to preserve the window's attributes, you could try adding this as the second line:

```
params.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
```

However, note that the `copyFrom` method is completely undocumented, so I have no idea if it does what it sounds like it does.

Comment: nope, doesn't seem to work with "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

Answer (score 2):

not 100% sure, but is it something to do with `params.gravity=Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;`?

another edit

ok then, this one should be of more use: [Calling android dialog without it fading the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113812/calling-android-dialog-without-it-fading-the-backgorund)

Comment: Not really, more like its in "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar". I.e. if its Theme.Dialog, then params work fine, but I get that modal shadow all over.

Comment: not really. The link's about removing that small shadow from the title bar, while I need to remove the model shading ( i.e. darkening of the whole screen behind the dialog ).

Answer (score 2):

In the above code the line...

```
dialog.show();
```

Should appear after

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
params.y = 225; params.x = 225;
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;       
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params); 
...
```

By the looks of things you are showing the dialog first then setting x,y coordinates after the dialog has already been drawn to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  and it will works. I've tried.