# Show Dialog without fading background

Tags: android, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling android dialog without it fading the backgorund](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113812/calling-android-dialog-without-it-fading-the-backgorund)

Is there any way to show a dialog (basically, `new Dialog(this).show()` ) that does not "fade" the background activity?

I don't want the activity behind to have focus but I want it to be clearly visible and not fade away.

Thanks

Comment: See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113812/calling-android-dialog-without-it-fading-the-backgorund

Answer (score 2):

This question already answered here [Calling android dialog without fading the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113812/calling-android-dialog-without-it-fading-the-backgorund)

Basically you could make a style resource in `res/values/styles.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="myBackgroundStyle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

then use it when you construct new dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.styles.myBackgroundStyle);
```

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate in situations like this instead of posting a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Dialog (Context context, int theme)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) constructor.
As `theme` parameter use Your own theme (similar to `com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_Dialog` used in dialog by default). For more details on theme, please check out data/res/themes.xml (Theme.Dialog) in You android platform directory. Basically You could just change dialog window background to transparent one.