# How to remove transparent dark background outside of dialog box

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to remove a transparent dark backgrond outside of dialog box.

[image]

**I tried with:**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);
         getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114466/2253407)

Code from the link:

Add this to your styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And then apply the theme to your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDim">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, saved much of my time!

Answer (score 36):

In addition to chuky's answer;

If your minSdkVersion value is greater than or equal to 14, you can use setDimAmount() method.

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(float amount);
```

According to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setDimAmount(float));

*amount*    The new dim amount, from 0 for no dim to 1 for full dim.

or

[As stated previously,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5757070/2558907) you can clear window flag.

Answer (score 19):

Hope this will help you...

```
dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.0f);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

i used background dim amount instead of background dim enabled

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(float amount);` caused my statusbar icons to disappear.

Clearing the `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` flag from window worked for me.

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```