# Android: bring View to the front of a Dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

## EDIT:

Current effect: [image current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O25ty.png)

Desired effect: [image desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voGWQ.png)

## Note

First of all, I tried `bringToFront` but it didn't work as expected.

## Explanation

When a Dialog is shown the background gets darker, I guess it's due to a new `Fragment` with a translucent black background being placed on top of the `Activity`.

In our Activity there is an `ImageButton` that we want the User to see. We show a `Dialog` explaining what the `ImageButton` is for, but we also want it not to be affected by the `Dialog` shadow. It's like a tutorial message.

## Future consideration

Also, please keep in mind that we will also transform the View (sizewise).

## iOS

My workmate made it easily in iOS with `bringToFront` and some transformations.

## Thanks

I haven't been able to do it in Android and haven't been able to successfully search it on Google neither Stack Overflow.

I think it's clear but I can provide an image later today if needed.
Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no other choice, but to create an `Activity`, put it on top and place another `ImageView` in the same spot, so that it covers the one behind.

To do so, I had to pass the `ImageView` position and size to the new `Activity` and place it correctly at `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

In your resources.xml file, add a new entry:

```
<style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

and then simply use this theme for your activity by changing the manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDim">
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21477766/6910818) by chuky

Comment: This erases the whole black background. It is not what I asked in the post.

Comment: You could try not using a dialog and using a view like textview instead. You could control its visibility dynamically, making it visible and invisible whenever you want. If you want, I can provide an example.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the post.

Comment: Can you provide some images please? Some of what you already have and one of what you want to achieve.