# Remove external dark background on Material Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

I need to remove the grey background outside the dialog, exactly as shown here: [How to remove transparent dark background outside of dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477484/how-to-remove-transparent-dark-background-outside-of-dialog-box)
Sadly, I'm working with Material Dialog, and it seems I can't call
`dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(float amount);`

Suggestions? Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **`android:backgroundDimAmount`** attribute (range: `1.0 - 0.0`):

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
</style>
```

or if you are using a MaterialComponents theme

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.xx</item>
</style>
```

and then just call:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_App_MaterialAlertDialog)
    //....
    .show()
```

With `0.2`:

[image]

With `0.8`:

[image]