# how to remove shadow in linearlayout in android?

Tags: android

i am designing a linear layout with rounded corner for custom dialog alert when it popups the white popup overlaps over black layout even without mentioning background as black which is shown with rounded in added image.i want to display popup with rounded corner with no black color part as mentioned in image,[image]

can anybody help me please.

customDialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@null"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="50"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@color/aa_text"
        android:textSize="25dp" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="50"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="message"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_lv_options"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popupBorder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="@color/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_ll_buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_positivebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_selector"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="@color/background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnBorder"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/background" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_negativebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/dialog_button_selector"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/background" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

rounded_corner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#eeeeee"/>
<stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#eeeeee" />
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip"     android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Dialog class, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114466/837714
Quote from there:

> Create a custom style and place it in your values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="YourCustomStyle" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

> To set a style to an individual dialog you can use

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.YourCustomStyle);
```

**UPDATE**

Move up from comments:

I misunderstood the question. Actual solution is:

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: no its not working it shows same issue.please check added image.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Try this solution: dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
android:elevation="0sp"
```

to remove the shadow. Works fine and you can still have a **background** set on the **LinearLayout**.

Comment: what about if we are API level <=19? elevation do not exist

Answer (score 0):

Put this property on the LinearLayout tag or element:

```
android:background="@color/fui_transparent"
```