# Remove grey background on Dialog with Custom theme that extends Theme.Dialog

Tags: android

I am using Accengage (Ad4Push) and I want to customize its dialog. Accengage team said that it is possible to change dialog style with custom theme and I did that. I can change textSize, textColor, windowBackground but I still see the grey color on Dialog. Please see my photo [Here](http://s22.postimg.org/ffhc563xt/Dialog.png). (I haven't got enough reputations to post an image)

I want to change all background dialog to white, but I don't know which attribute I can use for this purpose.

This is the attribute I am using.

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@color/background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@null</item>
        <item name="android:dividerVertical">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme.Button</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogTheme.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@color/background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

How I can make background of dialog become white. (I only can change the style with custom style, can not change programmatically, because this dialog come from third party library)

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate add this line.

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

checkout this post. 
[Dialog with transparent background in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795078/dialog-with-transparent-background-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113812/calling-android-dialog-without-it-fading-the-background/3114466#3114466)

Code from the link:

Add this to your styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.DoNotDim" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And then apply the theme to your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.DoNotDim">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your theme (thanks to [AAA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301473/aaa))

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

### full style:

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>  

    <item name="android:background">@color/background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHorizontal">@null</item>
    <item name="android:dividerVertical">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/CustomDialogTheme.Button</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I added it and the result still the same. It doesn't help.